# Show there's a disjoint partition over the sample space

Tags: probability

Been working on this problem - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Let $e \in\varepsilon$ be a simple function over $(\Omega,A,P)$. Show that there is a disjoint partition $A_i, i = 1,\ldots,m,$ of $\Omega$ such that $e =  \sum\limits_{i=1}\alpha_i1_{A_i}$.

Comment: Hint: By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function), $e$ is a finite linear combination of indicator functions. You can explicitly construct the $A_i$ from the supports of those indicator functions. If the procedure is not obvious, do an example with $m=2$.  BTW, what does "$\varepsilon$" stand for?  Do we even need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is simple if it has finite range. This is the definition given, for example, in Billingsley's probability book. If $\mathrm{Range}(f)=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$, and we define $A_i=\{\omega:f(\omega)=a_i\}$, for $i=1,\dots,n$, it is clear that we can represent a simple function $f$ as a sum of indicators
$$
  f(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i I_{A_i}(\omega) \, .
$$
Note that this representation is not unique (you can break each $A_i$ in many sets). Also, there are books that prefer to define simple functions directly as sums of indicators. It is easy to check that the sets $A_i$ form a partition of $\Omega$. Given distincts $A_i$ and $A_j$, there is no $\omega$ in $A_i\cap A_j$, because $f$ is a function, and by definition every function assigns only one value to each of its domain points. Hence, the sets $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint. Also, it is not difficult to see that $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i = \Omega$. Just check both inclusions.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your definition of a simple function is a function almost surely taking only finitely many values (I prefer say it is a simple random variable). Then take the $\alpha_i$ as the possible values of $e$ and define the events $A_i = \{e=\alpha_i\}$.

Comment: I do not think this will work: your construction only creates an $e'$ that could differ from $e$ on a set of measure zero. If there are a non-finite number of discrepancies, you will be in trouble. The problem lies not with your solution but with your definition.

Comment: @whuber Yes, you're right in some sense. But there's $P$ in the statement of the problem, so I consider that we consider random variables. From your point of view, $P$ plays no role.

Comment: Using the Wikipedia definition I cited, $P$ does not need to play any role at all. Thus, by adopting a more complicated definition than is needed (or likely intended), you have created a situation in which the statement in the question no longer is true, and so you have to change the sense in which you interpret it!

Comment: @whuber In this case, the question should be tagged *Analysis*, not *Probability*. There's no intention behind my reply, what do you mean ? I originally am probabilist and this was my natural reaction. Moreover the only thing I "change" is that I consider the equality at the end of the question as an almost sure equality. **Anyway I don't know the definition of the user**, so it was clumsy of me to write *I guess your definition..*.